# IBM Domino - get resource availability rules in Java XPage

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

I need to check against room's availability options if it's currently available in an java xpage rest api. I tried looking at the resource reservations database after setting custom availability options, but didn't get much info.
How can I check the availability rules programmatically? I know there is such thing as freetime api, but it's not really helpful and I don't want to use another service.

I found my room's document in the database and it looks like this:

```
{
    "@href":"\/RoomRese.nsf\/api\/data\/documents\/unid\/D6D558B1387CEA11C125842D002605C0",
    "@unid":"D6D558B1387CEA11C125842D002605C0",
    "@noteid":"902",
    "@created":"2019-07-04T06:55:18Z",
    "@modified":"2019-07-17T13:41:45Z",
    "@authors":"CN=Test User\/O=Server",
    "@form":"Resource",
    "actiontype":"SAVE",
    "ResourceType":"1",
    "Site":"Site",
    "ConferenceDatabase":"stconf.nsf",
    "InternetAddress":"room1@test.test",
    "Sunday":"1",
    "Monday":"2",
    "Tuesday":"3",
    "Wednesday":"4",
    "Thursday":"5",
    "Friday":"6",
    "Saturday":"7",
    "TimeZone":"Z=-1$DO=1$DL=3 -1 1 10 -1 1$ZX=27$ZN=Central European",
    "SundayAvailable":"1",
    "MondayAvailable":"2",
    "TuesdayAvailable":"3",
    "ThursdayAvailable":"5",
    "FridayAvailable":"6",
    "SaturdayAvailable":"7",
    "LimitHow":"1",
    "LimitDays":90,
    "LimitDate":"2019-10-02",
    "OtherComments":
    {
        "type":"multipart",
        "content":        [
                    {
            "contentType":"text\/html; charset=US-ASCII",
            "contentDisposition":"inline",
            "data":"<html><body><\/body><\/html>\r\n\r\n"
          }
        ]
    },
    "Type":"Resource",
    "Author":"CN=Test User\/O=Site",
    "CommonNameResourceName":"Room 1",
    "ResourceName":"CN=Room 1\/O=Site",
    "Capacity":44,
    "AlwaysAvailable":0,
    "AutoProcessType":"0",
    "Owner":"CN=Room 1\/O=Site"
}
```

I can see these 'MondayAvailabile' etc. but there are only simple numbers and I have no idea what do they mean.
How can I do it in java?

I have tried using session.freeTimeSearch() but it doesn't work, at least not on the server side. Here is my code:

```
        Session = resourceDB.getParent();
        DateRange = session.createDateRange();
        range.setStartDateTime(tStart);
        range.setEndDateTime(tEnd);

        int duration = tEnd.timeDifference(tStart);
        System.out.println("Range: " + range.getStartDateTime().toString() + " <-> " + range.getEndDateTime().toString());
        System.out.println("Duration calculated: " + duration);

        try {
            Vector<?> frs = session.freeTimeSearch(range, duration/2, "Room 1/Test Site",true);

            if(frs == null || frs.size() <= 0) {
                System.out.println("NO FREETIME !!!! " + tStart.toString() + " -> " + tEnd.toString());
                return true;
            } else {
                for(int i = 0; i < frs.size(); i++) {
                    DateRange dr = (DateRange)frs.elementAt(i);
                    System.out.println("Found " + dr.getStartDateTime().toString() + " <-> " + dr.getEndDateTime().toString());

                }
            }
        } catch (NotesException ex) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: "+ ex.getMessage());
        }
```

The output is like this:

```
Range: 07/18/2019 03:00:00 PM CEDT <-> 07/18/2019 03:30:00 PM CEDT
Duration calculated: 1800
NO FREETIME !!!! 07/18/2019 03:00:00 PM CEDT -> 07/18/2019 03:30:00 PM CEDT
```

I did duration/2 because I thought full-duration from daterange may not work, but it's the same.

**UPDATE!!** Stupid me, it works! The **duration** parameter should be in MINUTES, and the duration returned from timeDifference is in seconds, there fore a simple division by 60 fixed everything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Java API for querying free time. Look at `Session.freeTimeSearch()`.

Comment: I just tried and it kind of doesn't work on the server side. It keeps returning null even for rooms that are 24/7 available, I tried passing the room name in different ways, name without site throws an exception "Unable to find FreeTime for Names provided", canonical name doesn't throw any exception but returns null. I found this topic: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/xpagesforum.nsf/xpTopicThread.xsp?documentId=50F64B9EE866D98585257A6300260B43 unfortunately without any replies